# change an element in a list by numeric reference

Tags: r, list

I usually don't work with lists and I want to replace a number inside a list. It should be simple but I run into syntax problems. I know how to address the element:

```
test <- list(c(1,2,3))
test[[1]]==2
```

But by attempting to subset the list with this true/false vector it fails. My goal is:

```
goal <- list(c(1,4,3))
```

Comment: `test[[1]][2] <- 4`

Comment: `test[[1]][test[[1]]==2] <- 4`

Comment: thanks! Just missed one of those brackets...